# Como ingresar datos a un char en C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Estoy haciendo un programa en C++ de registro de pacientes con Hilos y con formularios, pero como puedo insertar de un Text Box a un char?
También tengo el siguiente error:

> E0020 el identificador "NodoMedico" no está definido
>   E0137 la expresión debe ser un valor L modificable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el código:

```
struct datosPaciente {
    char enfermedadP[20];
    char sintomas[200];
    char paciente[200];
    int dia, mes, año;
};

struct datosMedico {
    char medico[200];
    double sueldo;
};


struct NodoPaciente
{
    datosPaciente paciente;
    NodoPaciente *puntero;
};
    NodoPaciente *iniP, * finP;

void insertarNodoPaciente(char enfermedad[20]) {
    NodoPaciente *aux = new NodoPaciente;
    aux->paciente.enfermedadP=enfermedad;

    aux->puntero = NULL;
    if (iniP == NULL) {
        iniP = finP = aux;
    }
    else {
        finP->puntero = aux;
        finP = aux;
    }finP->puntero = NULL;
}
```

Por favor, cualquier ayuda en bienvenida

Comment: Lo primero que veo es que para para copiar un array de char no puedes usar el operador de igualdad, "=", sino usar la función strcpy (si quieres usar algo estándar).  La línea aux->paciente.enfermedadP=enfermedad; debería de ser strcpy(aux->paciente.enfermedadP,enfermedad). Por otro lado, y como mejora, deberías pasar el argumento de la función como const y por referencia. void insertarNodoPaciente(const char& enfermedad[20])

Comment: No me permite ingresar matríces en una referencia, según este error:
Error (activo) E0251 no se permite una matriz de referencia UPN C:\Users\Luis\source\repos\UPN\SouceNodos.h 19

Comment: Bueno, esto último era una sugerencia de mejora. ¿Te funciona lo de cambiar la forma de copiar el char? Recuerda que tienes que incluir la cabecera #include <cstring> para que pueda hacer uso de la función strcpy

Comment: No, me sale este error: 
Error (activo) E0167 un argumento de tipo "char" no es compatible con un parámetro de tipo "const char *" UPN C:\Users\Luis\source\repos\UPN\SouceNodos.h 22

Comment: ¿Que parámetro le pasas a la función? Mira que no sea un const char

Comment: He cambiado algunas cosas del método y del struct

struct NodoPaciente {
 char enfermedadP[50];
 char sintomas[200];
 char paciente[200];
 int dia, mes, año;
 NodoPaciente* puntero;
};
void insertarNodoPaciente(char &paciente, const char enfermedad, const char sintomas,int d,int m,int a) {
 NodoPaciente *aux = new NodoPaciente;
 strcpy(aux->paciente,paciente);
}
Pero nada

Comment: Te he puesto un ejemplo completo que compila.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código me funciona: (mira que he cambiado "año" por "anno", en el struct `datosPaciente`. También he cambiado la función `insertarNodoPaciente` para que haga uso de la función `strcpy` y he añadido la cabecera correspondiente `#include <cstring>`, como he puesto en el comentario. Mira la respuesta de @PaperBirdMaster, que es la mía pero mejor ;)

También

```
#include<cstring>
struct datosPaciente {
    char enfermedadP[20];
    char sintomas[200];
    char paciente[200];
    int dia, mes, anno;
};

struct datosMedico {
    char medico[200];
    double sueldo;
};

struct NodoPaciente
{
    datosPaciente paciente;
    NodoPaciente *puntero;
};
    NodoPaciente *iniP, * finP;

void insertarNodoPaciente(const char enfermedad[20]) {
    NodoPaciente *aux = new NodoPaciente;
    strcpy(aux->paciente.enfermedadP,enfermedad);

    aux->puntero = NULL;
    if (iniP == NULL) {
        iniP = finP = aux;
    }
    else {
        finP->puntero = aux;
        finP = aux;
    }finP->puntero = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    char enfermedad[20]= "Una enfermedad";
    insertarNodoPaciente(enfermedad);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Disculpa, pero una vez que tenga el dato, como lo puedo almacenar en un DataGriedView?

Comment: La verdad es que ahí ya no te puedo ayudar, porque eso suena a Visual C++ y yo no tengo ni idea de eso.

Comment: Pero transformar un const char a string?

Comment: Siguiendo con tu ejemplo podrías hacer: std::string cadena(aux->paciente.enfermedadP); o std::string cadena = aux->paciente.enfermedadP;  (obviamente una vez que le hayas asignado el valor a aux->paciente.enfermedadP.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Cómo puedo insertar de un Text Box a un `char`?

Podrías empezar llamando las cosas por su nombre. Ni tienes un Text Box ni tienes un `char`.

Estás igualando dos formaciones de tamaño estático `char datosPaciente::enfermedadP[20]` con el argumento `char enfermedad[20]` ¡y eso no puede hacerse!. Cada una de las formaciones tiene su espacio en memoria y no puedes cambiar una por otra.

Seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
NodoPaciente *aux = new NodoPaciente;
std::copy(enfermedad, enfermedad + 20, aux->paciente.enfermedadP);
```

---

Pero ya que estás programando en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), usa sus utilidades, cambia tus estructuras para usar `std::string`:

```
struct datosPaciente {
    std::string enfermedadP;
    std::string sintomas;
    std::string paciente;
    int dia, mes, año;
};

struct datosMedico {
    std::string medico;
    double sueldo;
};
```

Con `std::string` podrás hacer las cosas como querías:

```
void insertarNodoPaciente(const std::string &enfermedad) {
    NodoPaciente *aux = new NodoPaciente;
    aux->paciente.enfermedadP = enfermedad;

    aux->puntero = NULL;
    if (iniP == NULL) {
        iniP = finP = aux;
    }
    else {
        finP->puntero = aux;
        finP = aux;
    }finP->puntero = NULL;
}
```